# Writing a Personal Firewall in Java that drop network packet

Tags: java, firewall, jpcap

I would like to write a Personal Firewall on Java that can drop network packet. Is it possible?

I want to capture a packet on jpcap, but how can i do drop packet? Is there a library in this event on java?

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There is no way to do this. The answer can have been full if the question was appropriate.

Comment: Why the votes to close? It is certainly a real question and it is certainly answerable.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to write a Personal Firewall on Java that can drop
>   network packet. Is it possible?

No.

> I want to capture a packet on jpcap, but how can i do drop packet?

You can't drop packets with either `JPcap,` in any of its at least 3 incarnations, or its native component `libpcap/winpcap`.

> Is there a library in this event on java?

Not that I'm aware of, and I'm one of the authors of one of the `JPcaps` ;-)