# How to drop packets using JAVA Program

Tags: java, jpcap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a Personal Firewall in Java that drop network packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884408/writing-a-personal-firewall-in-java-that-drop-network-packet)

Hi friends I am new to this community. I am student of mtech. I am working on DOS attack detection and prevention technique as thesis. I am using jpcap library to capture the packet and I have an algorithm to find the spoofed packets. I want to drop spoofed packets to prevent the system from DoS attack. There is no class available in jpcap to drop the packets. Can anyone help me to find out a way to drop spoofed packets using JAVA program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing : there is no way to drop packets using `jpcap`

Comment: @EJP : the question this is marked duplicate of and is marked closed, is also closed on scope grounds. So that actually does not answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any java based API that will allow you to filter packets & as far as I am concerned there is no java API that supports this. none of the `pcap` libs : `jnetpcap,jpcap, winpcap` etc.

You would have to use `OS dependent firewall API` such as

microsoft's: [Microsoft firewall API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's right, WinPCAP can't drop packets.  But [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) (my own project) can.  It's written in C so OP would need to write a Java wrapper.

Comment: @basil wouldnt it be a better idea to use the `firewall api` than to wrap `windivert`? , not sure though. What do you say?

Comment: It depends.  For simple things like blocking based on traffic type, then the Windows user-mode firewall API may be OK.  For anything more complex things (e.g. that requires DPI) then you need to write kernel-mode software, or use a package like WinDivert.  PS: your above link is broken.

Comment: @Basil Alright, Thanks for the info. quite new to using java in these ways. Thanks for reporting the broken Link , I have updated it to a new link.

Comment: thanks mukul and basil for your responses. mukul your link is broken. can you send me new link and some tutorial about firewall api. i want to use them and basil thanks for windivert. i am studying windivert and i will try to use it. i want to know that can windivert drop packets using information like ipaddress of source machine, ttl values(means sort of rule generation)? and if i want to use windivert then i think i have to use jni.

Comment: @Ashok that URL has been fixed earlier today. open that first and then comment its working or not working

Comment: @Ashok Yes with WinDivert you can redirect packets to your application and "drop" them by simply not re-injecting them (for any reason you like).  Alternatively you can drop packets directly using `DIVERT_FLAG_DROP` flag (see the documentation).  This is useful for simple filters.